# using splice(0) to duplicate arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays: ArrayA and ArrayB. I need to copy ArrayA into ArrayB (as opposed to create a reference) and I've been using `.splice(0)` but I noticed that it seems to removes the elements from the initial array.

In the console, when I run this code:

```
var ArrayA = [];
var ArrayB = [];

ArrayA.push(1);
ArrayA.push(2);

ArrayB = ArrayA.splice(0);

alert(ArrayA.length);
```

**the alert shows 0**. What am I doing wrong with `.splice(0)`??

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Side note: [doNotForgetTheLowerCamelCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LowerCamelCase) `:)`

Comment: There's a difference between `.splice()` and `.slice()` ...

Comment: @sp00m: I like PascalNotation; I just think it looks better.

Comment: @frenchie I'm talking about conventions. PascaleNotation is reserved for classes, whereas lowerCamelCase is used for methods/functions and variables/attributes/properties.

Comment: @sp00m: I know about conventions but I really do prefer the looks of PascalNotation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You want to use `slice()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) and not `splice()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice))!

```
ArrayB = ArrayA.slice(0);
```

`slice()` leaves the original array untouched and just creates a copy.

`splice()` on the other hand just modifies the original array by inserting or deleting elements.

Answer (score 7):

`splice(0)` grabs all the items from `0` onwards (i.e. until the last one, i.e. all of them), **removes** them from the original array and returns them.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `slice`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
   ,b = a.slice();
//=> a = [1,2,3,4,5], b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

you can use `splice`, but it will *destroy* your original array:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
   ,b = a.splice(0);
//=> a = [], b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```